# Wiedemann-Franz law without without relaxation time approximation

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations

In Ashcroft-Mermin Chapter 16, it is written that the Wiedemann-Franz law holds even without the relaxation-time approximation, provided the following relation holds
\begin{equation}
\int dk' W_{k, k'}\ \epsilon(k') g(k') = \epsilon(k)\int dk' W_{k, k'}\ g(k')
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon(k)$ is the energy, $W_{k, k'}$ the scattering probability from $k$ to $k'$, and $g(k)$ the distribution function.

However, a derivation is not provided, nor is any reference given. I've tried to find a derivation online, yet have failed to acquire one. So, could anyone provide a reference where this derivation is done?

Answer (score 0):

This (and indeed most matters related to Boltzmann transport theory) is discussed in J. M. Ziman's classic book *Electrons and Phonons*, Oxford (1960). It's in Chapter VII, Section 4. However, you may find the derivation for the most general case (that is, when isotropy is not assumed) slightly hand-waving. That said, Ashroft-Mermin also claim that the law *only* holds under this assumption of elastic scattering. Although there is no reason to expect the law to hold in general, I am not aware of a direct proof of their claim.